# Dynamically loading file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny to build an interface for dealing with some files locally. I have a directory with three .dta files. I would like the user to be able to select a file and then view it.

server.R

```
output$choose_dta <- renderUI(selectInput('file',"Choose a file:", choices =
                                            c('file1','file2','file3')))
myData <-
  eventReactive(input$button,{
    foreign::read.dta(paste0("//my dir//",input$file,".dta"))
  })
output$table <- renderTable({
  data <- myData()
  data
})
```

ui.R

```
sidebarPanel(uiOutput('choose_dta'),actionButton('button','Load Data'))
mainPanel(tableOutput('table'))
```

I have a couple issues. One, the .dta files are large and require some time to load. Is it possible to make the page non-interactive (and make it clear that it is loading) while it is loading the data? Secondly, and more importantly, once the data loads (which I know because I get a warning from `read.dta`) the table never renders. How can I set up the table to render only once the data is loaded?

Kind Regards

Comment: You can use `withProgress` from Rshiny to indicate loading progress. here is an [Progress bar example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html).  And, For user to be able to select the data, [check this Github solution](https://gist.github.com/wch/4211337). It may bring you to your goal to select data to load and which data to render.

Answer (score 2):

First question: if you know some CSS, you could add some "masking/shield" element to the page (and give it a large zindex). Before starting to read, make it visible with shinyjs::show() and after reading remove it with shinyjs::hide().  That's one way to do it, there might be better ways.

Second question: perhaps it will work better if you use `reactiveValues`? For example, something like this (pseudocode):

```
values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
observeEvent(input$btn, {
  data <- read.csv(file)
  values$data <- data
})
output$table <- renderTable({
  values$data()
})
```

Try something like that maybe